# How to redirect a webpage using a proxy without servlet in java?

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking, proxy

My project is to create a proxy cache and to redirect the web page I am requesting.For example,if I type in and request stackoverflow.com , the proxy should redirect me to youtube.com . I have already written some lines of code to do this , but they don't seem to work.Sorry , I have never worked with proxies before.The project is in java and it has three classes : httprequest and httpresponse which are correct and proxycache,which is the class where the changes should be made.It has to be done without servlets.Thank you in advance!Here is my code so far:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ProxyCache {
    /** Port for the proxy */
    private static int port;
    /** Socket for client connections */
    private static ServerSocket socket;

    /** Create the ProxyCache object and the socket */
    public static void init(int p) {
    port = p;
    try {
        socket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating socket: " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    }

    public static void handle(Socket client) {
    Socket server = null;
    HttpRequest request = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;

    /* Process request. If there are any exceptions, then simply
     * return and end this thread. This unfortunately means the
     * client will hang for a while, until it timeouts. */

    /* Read request */
    try {
        BufferedReader fromClient = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Reading request...");

        request = new HttpRequest(fromClient);
        System.out.println("Got request...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading request from client: " + e);
        return;
    }
    /* Send request to server */
    try {
        /* Open socket and write request to socket */
            // NQS ESHTE PAGJATURE
            //if(request.getHost().include("www.stackoverflow.com")){
            //  server=new Socket=("www.plagiarism.com", 80);
            //    NQS ESHTE TIME WASTE
             //}else if(request.getHost().include("www.facebook.com")){
             //  server=new Socket("ajo e yt", 80);
            //}else{
                server = new Socket(request.getHost(), request.getPort());
      //} 

            DataOutputStream toServer = 
        new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
        toServer.writeBytes(request.toString());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        System.out.println("Unknown host: " + request.getHost());
        System.out.println(e);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing request to server: " + e);
        return;
    }
    /* Read response and forward it to client */
    try {
        DataInputStream fromServer = 
        new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        //InputStream is = server.getInputStream();

        response = new HttpResponse(fromServer);
        //response = new HttpResponse(is);
        DataOutputStream toClient =
            new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        toClient.writeBytes(response.toString());
        toClient.write(response.body);
        client.close();
        server.close();
        /* Insert object into the cache */
        /* Fill in (optional exercise only) */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing response to client: " + e);
    }
    }


    /** Read command line arguments and start proxy */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int myPort = 0;

    try {
        myPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Need port number as argument");
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please give port number as integer.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    init(myPort);

    /** Main loop. Listen for incoming connections and spawn a new
     * thread for handling them */
    Socket client = null;

    while (true) {
        try {
        client = socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Got connection " + client);
        handle(client);
        //ProxyCacheThread request = new ProxyCacheThread(client);
        //request.run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error reading request from client: " + e);
        /* Definitely cannot continue, so skip to next
         * iteration of while loop. */
        continue;
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: With all the code in one single class, you will surely get headache in no time, I suggest you to split your code like ```ListeningServer, ClientSource, ClientTarget```